# Avoid application email step in @SpringBootTest-annotated run of the entire application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit

My app's unit tests are annotated with `@SpringBootTest` which causes the entire application to run. One of the things the app does is send emails. I don't want any emails to go out at all, not even to a dummy address.

Is there a way to limit which part of the code should not be executed with `@SpringBootTest`, or how do I handle this situation? I'm not allowed to remove `@SpringBootTest`.

Comment: [SpringBootTest.#classes()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html#classes())!?

Comment: To *replace* your (complete) context for (spring boot) test, you can use an inner (static) `@Configuration` class...

Comment: I don't want to replace the complete context. I only want to substitute e.g. a Mock Email service in place of the real one.

Comment: ..in that (substitute) case: inner (static) `@TestConfiguration` class.;) (+`@Primary` on the according beans)

Comment: Or `@MockBean` ...

Answer (score 1):

If you can change your 'email sending code', one possibility would be to create a test specific profile and set a property to use in your code that decides whether or not emails should be sent.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles#7-activeprofile-in-tests

Another option would be to use a tool like Mailhog (https://github.com/mailhog/MailHog) to act as an SMTP server for your testing purposes.

Otherwise I am not familiar with any way to limit the code that is run through the @SpringBootTest annotation